# Remove headers in output in beeline

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, beeline

I am trying beeline cli to query hive table and store output result as variable.
Using beeline command:

```
beeline -u connection_string -n user_name -w password_file \
-e "select count(*) from db.table_name"
```

Using this command, I getting the current  output result as:

```
+---------------+--+ 
| record_count  | 
+---------------+--+ 
| 80785         | 
+---------------+--+
```

While I need result as: `Record count:80785`

Another command I am using is:

```
beeline -u connection_string -n user_name -w password_file \
-e "select * from db.table_name;” > result.csv
```

Which again displaying result in tabular format data separated by `|`.

Basically beeline, by default, is returning the header( `table_name.column_name`) then the data in tabular format. Whereas, I want to eliminate this and get results like hive CLI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use argument `--showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2` to illuminate this.

using THIS FORMAT YOUR command will be like

```
beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 \
-u connection_string -n user_name -w password_file \
 -e "select count(*) from db.table_name"
```

**Consider If tsv2 used**

```
id  value   comment
1   Value1  Test comment 1
2   Value2  Test comment 2
3   Value3  Test comment 3
```

If dsv used  (the delimiter is |)

```
id|value|comment
1|Value1|Test comment 1
2|Value2|Test comment 2
3|Value3|Test comment 3
```

Your data will look like this. Do remember these three are enabled with single quotes around the value if values are having special char or new line within. Quoting can be disabled by setting the disable.quoting.for.sv to true.

**SOME MORE OPTION USING CSV AND TSV**

> csv, tsv
>   These two formats differ only with the delimiter between values, which is comma for csv and tab for tsv.

when csv is used, data will look like this

```
'id','value','comment'
'1','Value1','Test comment 1'
'2','Value2','Test comment 2'
'3','Value3','Test comment 3'
```

And when tsv is used, then

```
'id'    'value' 'comment'
'1' 'Value1'    'Test comment 1'
'2' 'Value2'    'Test comment 2'
'3' 'Value3'    'Test comment 3'
```

**Just beware** while using **csv or tsv**, you will have single quote surrounded by value always and you can not get rid of it, which could lead to some problem in few cases.

Hope the above details explanation would cover all the possible cases you wanted to cover.

For more explanation visit the [Apache Beeline Wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-OutputFormats). cheers!!

Comment: Can you please explain `tsv2 ` stands for, and the advantages using this.

Comment: Here count is only an example, I need solution that can be used in all select query.

Comment: @SandeepSingh I updated my answer you can checkout now.

Comment: @SandeepSingh tsv gives `'col1'    'col2'   'col3' ...`  whereas tsv2 gives `col1    col2    col3 ...`  (imagine my spaces are actually TAB characters!).   
...So **tsv2** is what most developers think of as the "proper" tab-separated value format.

Answer (score 1):

Beeline has a bunch of [command line options.](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-BeelineCommandOptions)

In your case, you can use :

```
beeline --outputformat=dsv --showheader=false \
-e "select count(*) from db_name.table_name"
```

Comment: Can you please explain `dsv` stands for and advantages using this

Comment: `dsv` stands for delimiter separated value and it has no specific advantage in your case except for the fact that it'll suppress the table-like structure that beeline prints with hyphens and plus => `+-----+`